# Attaching Mendeley .bib to RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, pdflatex, bibtex, bibliography, biblatex

EDIT: Fixed first problem, but now I've got a different one.

I have been attempting to attach a bibliography generated by Mendeley to an RMarkdown document, but it's yielding a font error. I'm following instructions found [here](https://rosannavanhespenresearch.wordpress.com/2016/02/17/writing-your-thesis-with-rmarkdown-2-making-a-chapter/).

Here's the error:

```
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ￼ in font [lmroman12-
regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ￼ in font [lmroman12-
regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ￼ in font [lmroman12-
regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ￼ in font [lmroman12-
regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

Here is what my YAML looks like:

```
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
header-includes: \usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
fontsize: 12pt
bibliography: bib.bib
```

Here's a sample of the bib output from Mendeley:

```
@article{Bandelj2012,
abstract = {abstract {\textcopyright} The Author(s) 2012.},
author = {Bandelj, N. and Mahutga, M. C.},
doi = {10.1177/0020715212465097},
file = {:path/Bandelj, Mahutga - 2012 - Structures of globalization Evidence 
from the worldwide network of bilateral investment treaties (1959-
2009).pdf:pdf},
isbn = {0020-7152},
issn = {0020-7152},
journal = {International Journal of Comparative Sociology},
number = {2},
pages = {95--123},
title = {{Structures of globalization: Evidence from the worldwide network of 
bilateral investment treaties (1959-2009)}},
url = {http://cos.sagepub.com/cgi/doi/10.1177/0020715212465097},
volume = {54},
year = {2012}
}
```

Anyone have any tips on how to fix this? Any help greatly appreciated! Happy to provide more information.

Comment: The error is on line 200. Does your sample come from this location in the .bib file ?

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that. Now I've got a different error, so I revised the question.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't have the answer but I see you haven't got any in a forthweek, so maybe I can help a bit. I had other problems when trying to use a .bib generated by Mendeley with Rmarkdown and found [this](https://github.com/adamjgnoel/mendeleyBibFix) as a way to fix the .bib file generated by Mendeley. It didn't fix my issue but maybe you could give it a try.
Since it didn't help me, I am moving to zotero, maybe that manager will create an appropiate .bib.